# I wonder if this sentence is a shortened version of a certain sentence

Tags: grammar, american-english, writing

"Many vendors can be seen selling it now in the city."

I came across this sentence online which is quite strange to me in terms of sentence structure (grammar). why do 2 verbs "seen" "selling" stand together? I wonder if that's a shortened version of a full sentence such as relative clause reductions?

For example:
"We saw them selling it in the city" is a shortened version of this sentence: We saw them who was selling it in the city. (Relative clause reduction).

I am fine with the meaning of the sentence. I am just concerned about the grammar, the sentence structure.

I can easily understand this apparently similar sentence:

"Have you ever seen anyone walking the streets like that?"

But my sentence is quite different. Could someone show me the grammar point here? I still don't get how passive voice "can be seen" followed by a gerund "selling".

Comment: More accurately, a shortened version of the sentence: *We saw **those who were** selling it in the city.*

Comment: Your sentence is correct. I can understand it, it's called relative clause reduction. But my sentence is passive voice. It's different.